# How to close navigation bar when clicking anchor tag in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am struggling to find out how to close the navigation bar when in mobile view, when I click an anchor tag it just scrolls to the relevant section on the one page website. For example when in mobile view and when I user clicks on an anchor tag I would like it to scroll to the correct section and close. I am struggling to find an answer. I am new to javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll 
      to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: youngheart;
  src: url(fonts/Young\ Heart.ttf);
}


/* Global Preset */


/* Navigation Start */

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
}

nav img {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 12%;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: youngheart;
}

nav ul li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform .4s linear;
}

nav ul li a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}

label #btn,
label #cancel {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1118px) {
  nav img {
    left: 8%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 944px) {
  nav img {
    left: 6%;
    top: 20px;
    width: 130px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 860px) {
  label #btn {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #check:checked~ul {
    left: 0;
  }
  #check:checked~label #btn {
    display: none;
  }
  #check:checked~label #cancel {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
  </label>
  <img src="images/logo.png">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#shop">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#meet">Meet Our Team</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `css` class call (for example) "hide-mobile" with this code:

```
.hide-mobile {display:block !important;}
@media (max-width: 860px){
    .hide-mobile {display:none !important;}
}
```

and then in your `script`:

```
$("a").on('click', function(event) {
  if (this.hash !== "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function() {
      window.location.hash = hash;
      $("#btn").addClass("hide-mobile");  //THIS LINE
    });
  }
});
```

With this the `#btn` (or whatever element you want to hide) will be hidden after the scroll and with the `!important` out of the `mediaqueries` you'll make sure is always visible when not on mobile.

Just add another script to later remove the class when you want your navigation panel show again on mobile. For example is `scrollTop = 0` remove class

**EDITED:**
If you want to show again the element when no scroll backk to top this code may work :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() = 0){
            $('#btn').removeClass('hide-mobile');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would you implement the scrollTop = 0 script? Thanks very much